# Method overloading & Method Hiding in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, function-call, name-lookup

Why does the compiler not throw error in `main()` for `p->f4();` line.
As per my understanding class `B` hides `f4()` and should throw error

```
class A
{
    public:
        void f1(){}
        virtual void f2(){}
        virtual void f3(){}
        virtual void f4(){}
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
        void f1(){}
        void f2(){}
        void f4(int x){}
};


int main()
{
    A *p;
    B o2;
    p = &o2;
    
    p->f1();
    p->f2();
    p->f3();
    p->f4();  //why doesn't it throw an error for this line as class B hides f4()
    p->f4(5);  
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `o2.f4();` would be an error because of name hiding.

Answer (score 2):

The static type of the pointer `p` is `A *`. So for this call

```
p->f4();
```

the function `f4` is searched in the scope of the class `A` and is found and called. As the function is declared as virtual then if it would be overridden in the class `B` then the overriding function in the class `B` would be called.

But for this call

```
p->f4(5);
```

the compiler should issue an error because within the class `A` there is no function with the name `f4` that accepts an argument of the type `int`.